# return 0 for periods where data do not exist

Tags: mysql

I have a table (items_header) where I store some tickets with a creation date and I want to count how many have been created for each month/year. So far so good I can do it with the following query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_on, '%m-%Y') as 'period', COUNT(items_header.id) as 'total' 
FROM items_header JOIN progetti ON items_header.progetto=progetti.id 
WHERE progetto=1
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_on, '%m-%Y');
```

This query returns the data only for those months where at least a ticket have been created.

| period | total |
| --- | --- |
| 03-2022 | 2 |
| 04-2022 | 1 |
| 05-2022 | 3 |
| 06-2022 | 2 |

I have another table (progetti) where I store a start date and an end date for each project. For project 1 (the one in the example) dates are from 2022-01-01 to 2023-06-30 I'd like to add this information to the query so that it returns:

| period | total |
| --- | --- |
| 01-2022 | 0 |
| 02-2022 | 0 |
| 03-2022 | 2 |
| 04-2022 | 1 |
| 05-2022 | 3 |
| 06-2022 | 2 |
| 07-2022 | 0 |
| 08-2022 | 0 |
| 09-2022 | 0 |
| 10-2022 | 0 |
| 11-2022 | 0 |
| 12-2022 | 0 |
| 01-2022 | 0 |
| 02-2022 | 0 |
| 03-2022 | 0 |
| 04-2022 | 0 |
| 05-2022 | 0 |
| 06-2022 | 0 |

I started creating a join between the two tables but then got stuck on creating the expected result table.

EDIT table progetti:

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2023-06-30 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 |

Comment: Perhaps create a CTE that produces a list of all the months in your range, and then left join your items_header table against that?

Comment: @RobEyre yes, that's the point. but how to integrate that inside the query?

Comment: In case you're starting out on `JOIN` syntax: [A visual explanation of SQL joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/amp/).

Comment: thanks @Rogue no issue with JOIN. The issue was on joining a CTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a CTE that produces a list of all the months from the selected project then apply a `LEFT JOIN` to join this generated dates to your subquery :

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates AS 
(
    SELECT start_date as period, end_date
    FROM progetti
    WHERE id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_ADD(period, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), end_date
    FROM dates 
    WHERE DATE_ADD(period, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) < end_date
)
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(d.period, '%m-%Y') AS period, COALESCE(total, 0) AS total
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_on, '%m-%Y') as 'period', 
  COUNT(items_header.id) as 'total' 
  FROM items_header JOIN progetti ON items_header.progetto=progetti.id 
  WHERE progetto=1
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_on, '%m-%Y')
) s on s.period = DATE_FORMAT(d.period, '%m-%Y');
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/asOrR0vv)

Comment: thanks but there is not a "period" column on the progetti table. There is a start_date (2022-01-01) and a end_date (2023-06-30) fields. So the missing part is exactly how to build this "period" column

Comment: Could you edit your question and share some simple data from table progetti ?

Comment: edited to add a sample from the progetti table.

Comment: Can you check my recent edit

Comment: yes! That is what I was looking for. I had a similar CTE but was going nowhere on doing the Join. Now it is clear how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear I could help :)